# What happens when a cron keeps giving error but no redirections have been made to the log

Tags: linux, cron

I have a cron entry in cron tab. This cron runs every one minute. I forgot to give any redirections to messgaes and error. I wanted to know what happens to the error messages that arise from this cron. Do they get logged in a specific place. Also, does it consume a lot of additional space.

Answer (score 0):

If a cron job produces any output at all (no matter if it goes to stdout or stderr), the cron will send an email to the user owning that job.